# What is the basic structure in Netwire 5?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, reactive-programming, frp, netwire

I'm trying to get into Netwire, I've dug to find documentations, introductions, tutorials and whatnot, but just about every tutorial & existing-code is outdated as to Netwire 5 and uses functions from Netwire 4 that are just no longer with us. The [README](http://hub.darcs.net/ertes/netwire/browse/README.md) is kind of helpful, but not everything compiles and still it barely provides enough information to get started.

I am asking for explanation or an example just to get a game-loop running and being able to respond to events, so I seek information so I'll eventually know:

1. The basic structure (like how in reactive-banana you actuate network-descriptions that consume handlers, define behaviors and reactimate to events).
2. How it ultimately goes in `main`.
3. How to handle IO events (like a mouse-click, a key-down or a game-loop callback), how do events come in sessions, etc.

And anything else relevant.

I figure that from there I could get something running, and so I could learn the rest by experimentation (as the state of documentation and tutorials for this in the 5th version is horribly non-existent, I hope some will appear very shortly).

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't been able to find any large-scale programs that use Netwire, so everything I'm about to write you should take with a grain of salt, as it's based on my own experiences using Netwire. The examples that I use here are mostly taken [from my own library](http://www.github.com/Mokosha/Lambency) and [attempt at writing a game using FRP](https://github.com/Mokosha/HsTetrisAttack), and might not be "the right way" to do things.

---

#### Question 1: The basic structure (like how in reactive-banana you actuate network-descriptions that consume handlers, define behaviors and reactimate to events).

**Sessions:**
The author of the netwire library gave a [really good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787797/full-example-for-netwire/14789325#14789325) about the basic structure of a netwire program. Since it's a bit old, I will outline some of the points here. Before we look at wires, let's first take a look at how netwire handles time, the underlying driver of FRP. The only way to advance time without using the testing harness `testWire` is to produce a `Session` that will statefully return time deltas. The way `Sessions` preserve state is encapsulated in their type:

```
newtype Session m s = Session { stepSession :: m (s, Session m s) }
```

Here, a `Session` lies within a Monad (usually `IO`) and every time it is evaluated, returns a "time state" value of type `s` and a new `Session`. Usually, any useful state `s` can be written as a `Timed` value that can return some instance of `Real t`:

```
data Timed t s
class (Monoid s, Real t) => HasTime t s | s -> t where
    -- | Extract the current time delta.
    dtime :: s -> t
instance (Monoid s, Real t) => HasTime t (Timed t s)
```

For example, in games, you usually [want a fixed timestep](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) to do your update calls. netwire encodes this notion with:

```
countSession_ :: Applicative m => t -> Session m (Timed t ())
```

A `countSession_` takes as input the timestep, in this case a fixed value of type `t`, and produces a `Session` whose state values are of type `Timed t ()`. This means that they only encode a single value of type `t`, and do not carry any additional state with the `()` value. After we discuss wires, we will see how this plays a role in evaluating them.

**Wires:** The main type of a 'wire' in Netwire is:

```
Wire s e m a b
```

This wire describes a [reactive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) value of type `b` that does the following:

- Takes as input a reactive value of type `a`
- Operates within the Monad `m`
- May inhibit, or not produce a value, yielding an inhibition value of type `e`
- Assumes a time state given by `s`

By the nature of being reactive values, wires can be thought of as time-varying functions. Hence, each wire is encoded as a function of time (or the time state `s`) that produces, at that instant in time, a new value of type `b`, and a new wire with which to evaluate the next input of type `a`. By returning a value and a new wire, the function can encompass state by propagating it through the function definitions.

Additionally, wires may *inhibit* or not produce a value. This is useful for when computations are not defined (such as when the mouse is outside of the application window). This allows you to implement things like `switch`, where a wire changes to a different wire to continue execution (such as a player finishing his jump).

With these ideas, we can see the main driver of wires in netwire:

```
stepWire :: Monad m => Wire s e m a b -> s -> Either e a -> m (Either e b, Wire s e m a b)
```

`stepWire wire timestate input` does exactly what we said earlier: It takes a `wire` and passes it the current `timestate` and `input` from the previous wire. Then, in the underlying Monad `m`, it either produces a value of `Right b` or inhibits with a value of `Left e`, and then gives the next wire to use for the computation.

#### Question 2: How it ultimately goes in main.

Armed with values of type `Session` and `Wire`, we can construct a loop that does two things over and over:

1. Steps a session to receive a new time state
2. Uses the new time state to step a wire

Here is an example of a program that alters a fixed counter to count by twos forever:

```
import Control.Wire

-- My countLoop operates in the IO monad and takes two parameters:
--   1. A session that returns time states of type (Timed Int ())
--   2. A wire that ignores its input and returns an Int
countLoop :: Session IO (Timed Int ()) -> Wire (Timed Int ()) () IO a Int -> IO ()
countLoop session wire = do
  (st, nextSession) <- stepSession session
  (Right count, nextWire) <- stepWire wire st (Right undefined)
  print count
  countLoop nextSession nextWire

-- Main just initializes the procedure:
main :: IO ()
main = countLoop (countSession_ 1) $ time >>> (mkSF_ (*2))
```

#### Question 3: How to handle IO events (like a mouse-click, a key-down or a game-loop callback), how do events come in sessions, etc.

There is somewhat of a debate about how to do this. I think in this situation it's best to take advantage of the underlying Monad `m`, and simply pass a snapshot of the current state to the `stepWire` function. In doing so, most of my input wires look something like this:

```
mousePos :: Wire s e (State Input) a (Float, Float)
```

Where the input to the wire is ignored, and the mouse input is read from a `State` monad. I use `State` and not `Reader` in order to handle key debounces properly (so that clicking on UI doesn't also click on something underneath UI). The state is set in my `main` function and passed to `runState`, which also does the wire stepping. The inhibition behavior of wires like this can make for some elegant code. For example, suppose you have wires `right` and `left` for your arrow keys that produce a value if the key is pressed and inhibit otherwise. You can create character movement with a wire that looks like this:

```
(right >>> moveRight) <|> (left >>> moveLeft) <|> stayPut
```

Since wires are an instance of `Alternative`, if `right` inhibits, it'll just move on to the next possible wire. `a <|> b` will inhibit only if both `a` and `b` inhibit.

You could also write your code to take advantage of netwire's `Event` system, but you'd have to make your own wires that return an `Event` using `Control.Wire.Unsafe.Event`. That being said, I have yet to find this abstraction more useful than simple inhibition.

Comment: if we ever meet I'm going to buy you a beer for writing this answer

Answer (score 0):

It might be really late to answer this, but I have an answer here that contains the (minimalistic) structure of Netwire 5 program: [Console interactivity in Netwire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992299/console-interactivity-in-netwire)